# How to fix a gap in a Google Transit trip that spans the beginning/end of a loop?

Tags: general-transit-feed-specification, transit

In my GTFS data, I have bus routes that are on a loop and that is specified in my frequencies.txt. However, I noticed when querying trips on Google that if the trip crosses over the starting/end point of the loop it doesn't connect and it tells you to walk.

[image: Gap in bus route]

[Query example](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Whale+Park,+Sitka,+AK/Sea+Mart+Quality+Foods,+Halibut+Point+Road,+Sitka,+AK/@57.0511328,-135.3349032,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x54045d438ae8ac15:0x8a248aee94a7670f!2m2!1d-135.2530329!2d57.033688!1m5!1m1!1s0x5404664ee9295cc5:0x46205b2ec36703fe!2m2!1d-135.3667321!2d57.068146!2m3!6e0!7e2!8j1529917200!3e3)

My shapes.txt file draws out the full loop for the bus routes so I would expect everything to work but it always seems to have a gap from the last stop in stop_times.txt to the first.

Here are my GTFS files. https://github.com/joshuahouston/theRIDE/tree/gh-pages/feed_files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't closed my loop by adding the first stop again as the last stop. I didn't know about this handy page when I created this data and it helped me. http://gtfs.org/best-practices/#loop-routes